# Timed Variable Length Input from Keyboard

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to acquire input from a keyboard such that I create a variable length array of characters. The key is I need to be able to separate "phrases". By phrases I mean pauses in the user's typing. Which I am thinking of using some sort of timer for.

The goal is to remap a user's keyboard entry to a special character.

For example the user quickly types the letters "eafg" into the keyboard. This will map to some arbitrary symbol such as "*" within the application. The length of the input will range from 1 to 6 keys. The user might then pause for a very short time and type in "tys" which might translate to "&". Once I have the character array I have no problem mapping it. The problem is acquiring that array in the first place.

I know that I can use a Scanner object to get one line at a time; however I do not want the user to press enter at any time. I am thinking something like a character buffer in conjunction with some sort of timer would work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `java.awt.event.KeyAdapter.` to listen to keyboard and build your input strings. If you're building Swing GUI application use `javax.swing.timer`, otherwise `java.util.timer`.

Comment: Where are you receiving your input from? Terminal, JTextArea, JTextField...?

Comment: I'm receiving the input from console. Im simply trying to create a utility that remaps combination of keys to actions.